Weird "Ding" Sounds and Repeating PageUp Key on MacBook Pro M2 Max - How can I fix it?
I'm using a MacBook Pro with the Apple M2 Max chip, running macOS 15.1 (24B83).
A few days ago, I ran into a strange issue. After putting my MacBook Pro to sleep, my external Dell monitor turns on by itself. When I log back in, I hear rapid "ding" sounds, almost like a key is being pressed nonstop. It goes "ding ding ding ding..." very quickly.
I can't share a video here, but here's an audio clip that sounds similar:

To figure out what's going on, I used an online key test that counts how many times each key is pressed. The test showed that the PageUp key is being pressed repeatedly:

I searched online and found suggestions that it might be related to Bluetooth devices. I do use a Bluetooth keyboard (bought from the official Apple Store, fully charged) and it's been working fine for years. I tried disconnecting the keyboard's Bluetooth connection, but the issue persisted.
However, when I turned off Bluetooth on my MacBook Pro entirely, the problem went away.
This is so weird. Can anyone tell me what might be causing this? I can use the keyboard by connecting it to my MBP, but I can't use my MBP without bluetooth features.
